# How can one convert numerous nested if-else statements into a sentinel-controlled while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, leap-year, sentinel

I'm having trouble with the sentinel-controlled loop structure of the lab I am in. I am supposed to make a program that can determine whether a year is a leap-year or a regular year. So far my professor said I have the boolean logic and the input ok, but I'm clueless how to set a sentinel controlled while loop that keeps on asking for an input until the user provides the program with the value that triggers the EOF command and terminates the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a year (0 to end)?");
        int year = S.nextInt();
        if (year > 1752) {
            if (((year%4)== 0) && ((year%100)==0) && ((year%400)==0)) {
                System.out.print("Leap Year");
            } else if (((year%4)== 0) && ((year%100)==0) && ((year%400)!=0)) {
                System.out.println("Regular Year");
            } else if ((year%4)== 0) {
                System.out.print("Leap Year");
            }
            else 
                System.out.print("Regular Year");
        }
        else 
            System.out.print ("Please enter a year after 1752");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solution, in your case the most suitable could be a `do..while` statement:

```
do
{
  // your code
}
while (condition); // condition to keep looping: input year not zero
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer: you will need to set a variable `true` or `false` depending on whether you had a valid input or not, and test for that variable in the `condition`. The `// your code` would be most of the stuff you have in your `main` program right now.